# skip leading number in regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract the real issue number in my file name. There are 2 patterns:

1. if there is no leading number in the file name, then the number, which we read first, is the issue number. For example

```
asdasd 213.pdf             ---> 213
abcd123efg456.pdf          ---> 123
```

2. however, sometimes there is a leading number in the file name, which is just the index of file, so I have to ignore/skip it firstly. For example

```
123abcd 4567sdds.pdf    ---> 4567, since 123 is ignored

890abcd 123efg456.pdf   ---> 123, since 890 is ignored
```

I want to learn whether it is possilbe to write only one regular expression to implement it? Currently, my soluton involves 2 steps:

1. if there is a leading number, remove it
2. find the number in the remaining string

or in Python code

```py
import re

reNumHeading = re.compile('^\d{1,}', re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE) # to find leading number
reNum = re.compile('\d{1,}', re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE) # to find number


lstTest = '''123abcd 4567sdds.pdf
asdasd 213.pdf
abcd 123efg456.pdf
890abcd 123efg456.pdf'''.split('\n')

for test in lstTest:
    if reNumHeading.match(test):
        span =  reNumHeading.match(test).span()
        stripTest = test[span[1]:]
    else:
        stripTest = test

    result = reNum.findall(stripTest)
    if result:
        print(result[0])
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `?` quantifier to define optional pattern

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''asdasd 213.pdf
... abcd123efg456.pdf
... 123abcd 4567sdds.pdf
... 890abcd 123efg456.pdf'''
>>> for line in s.split('\n'):
...     print(re.search(r'(?:^\d+)?.*?(\d+)', line)[1])
... 
213
123
4567
123
```

- `(?:^\d+)?` here a non-capturing group and `?` quantifier is used to optionally match digits at start of line

  - since `+` is greedy, all the starting digits will be matched
- `.*?` match any number of characters minimally (because we need the first match of digits)
- `(\d+)` the required digits to be captured
- `re.search` returns a `re.Match` object from which you can get various details
- `[1]` on the `re.Match` object will give you string captured by first capturing group

  - use `.group(1)` if you are on older version of Python that doesn't support `[1]` syntax

See also: [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 3):

Just match digits `\d+` that follow a non-digit `\D`:

```
import re

lstTest = '''123abcd 4567sdds.pdf
asdasd 213.pdf
abcd 123efg456.pdf
890abcd 123efg456.pdf'''.split('\n')

for test in lstTest:
    res = re.search(r'\D(\d+)', test)
    print(res.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
4567
213
123
123
```